# Alternating attributes on a page laravel

Tags: html, laravel

migration

```
Schema::create('blogs', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('title');
        });
```

controller

```
public function index()
    {
        $blog= Blog::all();

        return view('blog', compact('blogs'));
    }
```

We have something like this code on the blog page

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
@foreach($blogs as $blog)
    <div class="blog-list">
        <div class="blog blog--left">
            <h2 class="blog_title">{{ $blog->title }}</h2>
        </div>

        <div class="blog blog--right">
            <h2 class="blog_title">{{ $blog->title }}</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
</div>
@endsection
```

Where at the output we get:

> Blog 1 (blog--left)
> Blog 1 (blog--right)
> Blog 2 (blog--left)
> Blog 2 (blog--right)
> Blog 3 (blog--left)
> Blog 3 (blog--right)
> Blog 4 (blog--left)
> Blog 4 (blog--right)

How to make alternation so that at the exit we get:

> Blog 1 (blog--left)
> Blog 2 (blog--right)
> Blog 3 (blog--left)
> Blog 4 (blog--right)

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question in sentence format. Don't make us all trudge in here to see what you're on about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a modulus operator for this as long as you have the index reference.

```
@foreach ($blogs as $index => $blog)
    <div class="blog-list">
        @if ($index % 2 === 1) 
            <div class="blog blog--left" >
                <h2 class="blog_title">{{ $blog->title }}</h2>
            </div>
        @else

            <div class="blog blog--right">
                <h2 class="blog_title">{{ $blog->title }}</h2>
            </div>
        @endif
    </div>
@endforeach
```

The modulus operator here: `@if ($index % 2 === 1)` will always be `true` when the result is `odd`, and if it's not odd, then it's `even` which will instead print in the `blog--right` column.

Comment: thanks, I'll check it later, I'll write the result